# Best way to get copy of remote XML?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, xml

I need access to a couple of XML files on a remote server. Because of the crossdoamin policies, i cannot do it with jQuery alone, but need a small c# .aspx page, which will act as a gateway for my jQuery to fetch the remote xml from a local file. But how would i best go about this page - what is the simplest structure of such a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a "[Generic Handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx)" (ASHX file).

I'll use these kind of files often when sending files to the browser, without the need for an UI (i.e. no visible page content).

In my understanding I see ASHX handlers as "pages without an UI" that have low overhead compared to a normal [`Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Why not a web service?

```
client code (jQuery) -> your server (WCF) -> external xml
```

You can quickly create a REST web service with [this template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd).